# Typescript readonly object literals

Tags: typescript

I have a complex data model in which I need to define let's say 40-50 singleton "metadata" objects that:

- use Discriminated Unions
- have some regular fields but also a Dictionary which can contain an arbitrary number of objects belonging to a Discriminated Union

I would like to be able to keep the implicit type created for the object literal so that I can manipulate those 40-50 objects in a type-safe manner with intellisense.

Here is an example using the Shapes from [typescript's documentation for Advanced Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```js
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
type Shapes = { [x: string]: Shape };

interface Canvas { 
    name: string;
    size: number;
    //etc
}
interface Drawing extends Canvas {
    shapes: Shapes;
}

//compiles but does not give me intellisense on drawingExplicitType.shapes because it is a Dictionary 
let drawingExplicitType: Drawing = {
    name: 'myDrawing',
    size: 100,
    shapes: {
        c: { kind: "circle", radius: 1 },
        r: { kind: "rectangle", width: 1, height: 1 },
    }
};

//compiles and gives me intellisense on drawingImplicitType.shapes
let drawingImplicitType = {
    name: 'myDrawing',
    size: 100,
    shapes: {
        c: { kind: "circle", radius: 1 },
        r: { kind: "rectangle", width: 1, height: 1 },
    }
};
//will have many objects like drawingImplicitType (around 40-50) which I want to manipulate in a type safe manner
//also the shapes will have sub-shapes, so it's a tree-like data model

//I still want to be able to put all "drawing*" objects in an array of Drawing(s)
//ERROR!!! does not compile: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"circle"'.
let drawing: Drawing = drawingImplicitType;


//## workaround ##########################################

class Drawing2 implements Canvas {
    name: string;
    size: number;
    shapes: Shapes;

    fromObjLiteral<T extends Pick<Drawing2, Exclude<keyof Drawing2, 'shapes' | 'fromObjLiteral'>> & {shapes: any}>(
        obj: T & {shapes: {readonly [x in keyof T['shapes']]: Shape}}): Drawing2 
    {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
        return this;
    }
}

//compiles and gives me intellisense on drawingImplicitType2.shapes
let drawingImplicitType2 = new (class {
    name = 'myDrawing';
    size = 100;
    shapes = new (class {
        c = new (class { readonly kind = "circle"; radius = 1 })();
        r = new (class { readonly kind = "rectangle"; width = 1; height = 1 })();
    })();
})();

let drawing2: Drawing2 = new Drawing2().fromObjLiteral(drawingImplicitType2);
let array: Drawing2[] = [drawing2];
//The workaround compiles and still allows me to make arrays of Drawing2(s) 
//But I have to create new objects and the syntax is super ugly compared to:
//let drawingImplicitType2 = readonly {...obj literal here...}
```

**EDIT 2018-05-25**

As [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) pointed out type assertions would be simpler to use, however we need to use them on all sub-objects to get strong type safety. This can be a bit annoying with a recursive tree-like data model where `Shape`s can contain other `Shape`s but I think it's better than `new (class {...})()`

```js
//type assertions compile but allow me to make all kinds of errors:
let drawingTypeAssertion = {
    name: 'myDrawing',
    size: 100,
    nonExistentField: 123,
    shapes: {
        c: { kind: "circle", radiusWrongField: 1 },
        r: { kind: "rectangle", width: 1, height: 1 },
    }
};
let drawingTA: Drawing = drawingImplicitType as Drawing;

//#####################################################################
// workaround 2: deep type assertions
//#####################################################################

let drawingDeepTypeAssertion = {
    name: 'myDrawing',
    size: 100,
    nonExistentField: 123,
    shapes: {
        c: { kind: "circle", radius: 1 } as Shape,
        r: { kind: "rectangle", width: 1, height: 1 } as Shape,
    }
};
let drawingDTA: Drawing = drawingImplicitType as Drawing;
let array2: Drawing[] = [drawingDTA];
//This workaround compiles and still allows me to make arrays of Drawing2(s)
//no need to create extra objects and the syntax is a bit nicer than new (class {...})()
```

*END EDIT 2018-05-25*

One big downside of *workaround 2* is that as soon as you do `as Shape` you lose the implicit type and go-to-definition in vscode.

As I understand it, the problem comes from the fact that the object literals are mutable and the discriminated unions will not work. Mainly because the mutability causes the type of *discriminant* field `kind` to be `string` instead of `'square'` or `'rectangle'`.

There is much discussion about deep readonly and "const":
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10725
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300

Is there a better workaround with the current version of typescript than the ones above?

[Link to typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Square%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20%22square%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Rectangle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20%22rectangle%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Circle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20%22circle%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20radius%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20Shape%20%3D%20Square%20%7C%20Rectangle%20%7C%20Circle%3B%0D%0Atype%20Shapes%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Shape%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Canvas%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fetc%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Drawing%20extends%20Canvas%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20Shapes%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fcompiles%20but%20does%20not%20give%20me%20intellisense%20on%20drawingExplicitType.shapes%20because%20it%20is%20a%20Dictionary%20%0D%0Alet%20drawingExplicitType%3A%20Drawing%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'myDrawing'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20100%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%20radius%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22rectangle%22%2C%20width%3A%201%2C%20height%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fcompiles%20and%20gives%20me%20intellisense%20on%20drawingImplicitType.shapes%0D%0Alet%20drawingImplicitType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'myDrawing'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20100%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%20radius%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22rectangle%22%2C%20width%3A%201%2C%20height%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Fwill%20have%20many%20objects%20like%20drawingImplicitType%20(around%2040-50)%20which%20I%20want%20to%20manipulate%20in%20a%20type%20safe%20manner%0D%0A%2F%2Falso%20the%20shapes%20will%20have%20sub-shapes%2C%20so%20it's%20a%20tree-like%20data%20model%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FI%20still%20want%20to%20be%20able%20to%20put%20all%20%22drawing*%22%20objects%20in%20an%20array%20of%20Drawing(s)%0D%0A%2F%2FERROR!!!%20does%20not%20compile%3A%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%22circle%22'.%0D%0Alet%20drawing%3A%20Drawing%20%3D%20drawingImplicitType%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Ftype%20assertions%20compile%20but%20allow%20me%20to%20make%20all%20kinds%20of%20errors%3A%0D%0Alet%20drawingTypeAssertion%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'myDrawing'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20100%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nonExistentField%3A%20123%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%20radiusWrongField%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22rectangle%22%2C%20width%3A%201%2C%20height%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20drawingTA%3A%20Drawing%20%3D%20drawingImplicitType%20as%20Drawing%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0D%0A%2F%2F%20workaround%201%3A%20anonymous%20class%20instancess%0D%0A%2F%2F%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Drawing2%20implements%20Canvas%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20Shapes%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fromObjLiteral%3CT%20extends%20Pick%3CDrawing2%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20Drawing2%2C%20'shapes'%20%7C%20'fromObjLiteral'%3E%3E%20%26%20%7Bshapes%3A%20any%7D%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20T%20%26%20%7Bshapes%3A%20%7Breadonly%20%5Bx%20in%20keyof%20T%5B'shapes'%5D%5D%3A%20Shape%7D%7D)%3A%20Drawing2%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fcompiles%20and%20gives%20me%20intellisense%20on%20drawingImplicitType2.shapes%0D%0Alet%20drawingImplicitType2%20%3D%20new%20(class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%20%3D%20'myDrawing'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20100%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%20%3D%20new%20(class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%20%3D%20new%20(class%20%7B%20readonly%20kind%20%3D%20%22circle%22%3B%20radius%20%3D%201%20%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%20%3D%20new%20(class%20%7B%20readonly%20kind%20%3D%20%22rectangle%22%3B%20width%20%3D%201%3B%20height%20%3D%201%20%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20drawing2%3A%20Drawing2%20%3D%20new%20Drawing2().fromObjLiteral(drawingImplicitType2)%3B%0D%0Alet%20array%3A%20Drawing2%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bdrawing2%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2FThis%20workaround%20compiles%20and%20still%20allows%20me%20to%20make%20arrays%20of%20Drawing2(s)%20%0D%0A%2F%2FBut%20I%20have%20to%20create%20new%20objects%20and%20the%20syntax%20is%20super%20ugly%20compared%20to%3A%0D%0A%2F%2Flet%20drawingImplicitType2%20%3D%20readonly%20%7B...obj%20literal%20here...%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0D%0A%2F%2F%20workaround%202%3A%20deep%20type%20assertions%0D%0A%2F%2F%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20drawingDeepTypeAssertion%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'myDrawing'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20100%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nonExistentField%3A%20123%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shapes%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%20radius%3A%201%20%7D%20as%20Shape%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%3A%20%7B%20kind%3A%20%22rectangle%22%2C%20width%3A%201%2C%20height%3A%201%20%7D%20as%20Shape%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20drawingDTA%3A%20Drawing%20%3D%20drawingImplicitType%20as%20Drawing%3B%0D%0Alet%20array2%3A%20Drawing%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5BdrawingDTA%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2FThis%20workaround%20compiles%20and%20still%20allows%20me%20to%20make%20arrays%20of%20Drawing2(s)%0D%0A%2F%2Fno%20need%20to%20create%20extra%20objects%20and%20the%20syntax%20is%20a%20bit%20nicer%20than%20new%20(class%20%7B...%7D)()%20%0D%0A).

Comment: I think the simplest workaround is a type assertion: `let drawing: Drawing = drawingImplicitType as Drawing;`

Comment: Hey @AlekseyL., thanks for the reply, I updated the playground, type assertions allow me to compile but also allow me to make all kinds of mistakes...
The `nonExistentField` mistake I can make with the `new (class` workaround too, but I cannot mess up instances of Shape by mistake

Comment: @AlekseyL. I could do `as Shape` on each of the `Shape` sub-objects...I'll play around a bit and see if this is a better approach than the `new (class...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon a similar problem and found another solution:

From typescript 3.5 you can also use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and then:

```
let drawingTypeAssertion = {
  name: 'myDrawing',
  size: 100,
  nonExistentField: 123,
  shapes: {
     c: { kind: "circle", radiusWrongField: 1 },
     r: { kind: "rectangle", width: 1, height: 1 },
  }
// Add this assertion here
} as const;
```

That would make **all** of your properties readonly.